# Why are the song details not displaying in the liked.handlebars view?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using using Node.js, Express.js, Handlebars.js, and MySQL to create a website where you can login and share songs. I've setup a LikedSong model that relates the liked song to the user that likes it, and routes that allow a user to like a song and attempt to view liked songs.

The problem is that when triggering the page to view liked songs the song's information isn't displayed.

Liking a song registers properly in its table in MySQL Workbench., and the console.log of the array of liked songs in my route returns all of the song's information before trying to send it over to the handlebars page

Route to view liked songs:

```
router.get("/liked", withAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const likedSongs = await LikedSong.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: req.session.user_id,
      },
      include: [Song],
    });

    // Add liked songs associated with the user to the songs array
    const songs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < likedSongs.length; i++) {
      songs.push(await likedSongs[i].getSong());
    }
    console.log("songs =", songs);

    res.render("liked", {
      songs,
      loggedIn: req.session.loggedIn,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

===============================================================

Console.log('songs =", songs) result:

```
songs = [
  song {
    dataValues: {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Playing God',
      artist: 'Polyphia',
      album: 'Remember That You Will Die',
      embed: '<iframe style="border-radius:12px"\n' +
        '    src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/3nBGFgfRQ8ujSmu5cGlZIU?utm_source=generator"\n' +
        '    width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay;\n' +
        '    clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>',
      genre_id: 1,
      createdAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Playing God',
      artist: 'Polyphia',
      album: 'Remember That You Will Die',
      embed: '<iframe style="border-radius:12px"\n' +
        '    src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/3nBGFgfRQ8ujSmu5cGlZIU?utm_source=generator"\n' +
        '    width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay;\n' +
        '    clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>',
      genre_id: 1,
      createdAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  song {
    dataValues: {
      id: 7,
      title: 'Solo',
      artist: 'Samsa',
      album: 'Solo',
      embed: '<iframe style="border-radius:12px"\n' +
        '    src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/0oinJU5psqs6JSRT1k9Wfz?utm_source=generator"\n' +
        '    width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write;\n' +
        '    encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>',
      genre_id: 2,
      createdAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 7,
      title: 'Solo',
      artist: 'Samsa',
      album: 'Solo',
      embed: '<iframe style="border-radius:12px"\n' +
        '    src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/0oinJU5psqs6JSRT1k9Wfz?utm_source=generator"\n' +
        '    width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write;\n' +
        '    encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>',
      genre_id: 2,
      createdAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  song {
    dataValues: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Music to Clean the House to',
      artist: 'Nick Leng',
      album: 'LEMONS',
      embed: '<iframe style="border-radius:12px" \n' +
        '    src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/18HzHlxWPLoJjEXJdzNf4V?utm_source=generator" \n' +
        '    width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; \n' +
        '    encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>',
      genre_id: 5,
      createdAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Music to Clean the House to',
      artist: 'Nick Leng',
      album: 'LEMONS',
      embed: '<iframe style="border-radius:12px" \n' +
        '    src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/18HzHlxWPLoJjEXJdzNf4V?utm_source=generator" \n' +
        '    width="100%" height="352" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; \n' +
        '    encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>',
      genre_id: 5,
      createdAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-08-26T20:40:08.000Z
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

====================================================

liked.handlebars:

```
<section class="genre">
  {{#if songs.length}}
    {{#each songs as |song|}}
      <div class="song-details">
        <h3>{{song.title}}</h3>
        <p>Album: {{song.album}}</p>
        <p>By: {{song.artist}}</p>
        {{{song.embed}}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <h3>No liked songs found!</h3>
  {{/if}}
</section>
```

==================================================

The only thing that is displayed on the liked.handlebars page is the text that isn't trying to pull the song's information.

So only

"Album:

By: "

or "No liked songs found!"

if I've yet to like a song.

Thank you for any help you can provide! I've been trying to wrap my head around this to fix it for a while with no success, let me know if you need any more information

Comment: I believe the console.log shows an array with only one object in it. If I like a second song, the console.log displays as many songs as the user has liked. I'll update my post to reflect this!

Comment: Can you post the exact console output from `console.log("songs =", songs);` please?

Comment: I've updated the post with the full `console.log("songs = ", songs);` output, including three liked songs. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: OK, I see. Let me take a look.

Comment: In the `console.log('songs =", songs) result` above, did you add in the word `song` before each object or was that in the actual console output? If you did that will affect the path traversal.

Comment: The word song before each object is in the actual console output. I'm not sure how, but it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have just have to step another level deeper into your objects. Try this:

If this is your array:

```
songs = [
   {
      song: {
         dataValues: {
            id: 3,
            //...
         },
         //...
      }
   },
]
```

Then your handlebars will look like this:

```
<section class="genre">
    {{#if songs.length}}
        {{#each songs}}
            <div class="song-details">
                <h3>{{this.song.dataValues.title}}</h3>
                <p>Album: {{this.song.dataValues.album}}</p>
                <p>By: {{this.song.dataValues.artist}}</p>
                {{{this.song.dataValues.embed}}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <h3>No liked songs found!</h3>
    {{/if}}
</section>
```

However, if this is your array:

```
songs = [
   {
      dataValues: {
         id: 3,
         //...
      },
      //...
   },
]
```

Then your handlebars will look like this:

```
<section class="genre">
    {{#if songs.length}}
        {{#each songs}}
            <div class="song-details">
                <h3>{{this.dataValues.title}}</h3>
                <p>Album: {{this.dataValues.album}}</p>
                <p>By: {{this.dataValues.artist}}</p>
                {{{this.dataValues.embed}}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <h3>No liked songs found!</h3>
    {{/if}}
</section>
```

Comment: You're right! The formatting of `<h3>{{this.dataValues.title}}</h3>` worked! Thank you for helping me work through this!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project and [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) is a link to the handlebars helpers docs.